# D3 zooming into an arbitrary set of points on a map

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, geo

I'm using D3's mapping capabilities to show a map and would like to display a set of points specified in (lat,lon) coordinates.  I can do this, however, now I'm trying to figure out how to programatically zoom into a bounding box that contains all of the points.

What's the best/easiest way to do this with D3?

I've looked at the tutorials online and most are based on zooming into a specific feature (i.e. path), but I couldn't figure out how to zoom into an arbitrary set of lat/lon points.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or provide some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the two zooming examples to get you started:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680999

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680957

If you're not already using a quad-tree for your points you may consider it:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quadtree-Geom

You would then use the `d3.quadtree.extent()` to find the bounding box for your data.